Reformat complex file output from an old fortran program to csv using python
I want to convert complex file output into a simpler version, but I can't seem to get the regex right.
I have tried using regex and pandas to convert this weird formatted code to something nicer but the code I'm using just gives headers and not data. The data looks like this (be warned it's horrible), the sample file is here:  https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d5c0588d5dd08d0e67ddf854d4a3c3bb20240906142948/0d9147.
Weather Summary for summer 2024





Rainfall
Air Temperature
Sunshine
Wind
Grass Temp






Most in Day
Means  of

Extreme Temperature
Most in Day
Lowest



Total
______
_____
______
_____
_____
_____
Total
_____
Grass   date


Station

Amount
Date
Max.
Min.
Max
Min

Date
min


___________________
_______
______
_____
______
_____
_____
_____
________
_____
______________


station 1
121.5
13.4
29 Ju
19.7
10.2
26.6
4.5
--
--
-0.7   19 Ju


___________________
_______
______
_____
______
_____
_____
_____
________
_____
______________


station 2
235.9
21.1
26 Ag
16.6
11.9
21.9
6.5
--
--
-1.3   11 Ju















___________________
_______
______
_____
______
_____
_____
_____
________
_____
______________


station 3
135.7
13.6
29 Ju
19.3
10.1
24.0
3.5
--
--
-0.7   12 Ju


___________________
_______
______
_____
______
_____
_____
_____
________
_____
______________



I want to get it in simple csv format but I can't figure it out.
Screenshot of what it looks like is here: 
My latest code:
import re 
import csv

#Input and output file paths
input_file = 'table_example.txt
output_file = 'weather_summary.csv

# Define a function to parse the file and extract the table data
def parse_weather_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    # List to hold the processed rows
    data = []

    # Regex to match valid data rows (ignoring separators and headers)
    pattern = re.compile(r'\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|')

    for line in lines:
        match = pattern.match(line)
        if match:
            # Extract matched groups and clean the values
            row = [group.strip() for group in match.groups()]
            data.append(row)

    return data

# Define a function to write data to CSV
def write_to_csv(data, output_file):
    # Column headers
    headers = [
        "Station", "Rainfall Total", "Most in Day (Amount)", "Most 
in Day (Date)",
        "Max Air Temp", "Min Air Temp", "Mean Air Temp", "Max 
Temp", "Max Temp Date",
        "Min Temp", "Min Temp Date", "Sunshine Total", "Most in Day 
Sunshine (Amount)",
        "Most in Day Sunshine (Date)", "Max Wind Gust", "Max Wind 
Gust Date", 
        "Grass Min Temp", "Grass Min Temp Date"
    ]

    with open(output_file, mode='w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(headers)  # Write the headers
        writer.writerows(data)  # Write the data rows`

# Parse the weather data from the input file
weather_data = parse_weather_data(input_file)

# Write the parsed data to CSV
write_to_csv(weather_data, output_file)

EDIT
Updated code which gives the dataframe but it's still messy:
data = pd.read_csv('example_table.txt', sep="|", header=None, skiprows = 8)

data.columns = [
    "Station", "Rainfall Total", "Most in Day (Amount)", "Most in Day (Date)",
    "Max Air Temp", "Min Air Temp", "Mean Air Temp", "Max Temp", "Max Temp Date",
    "Min Temp", "Min Temp Date", "Sunshine Total", "Most in Day Sunshine (Amount)",
    "Most in Day Sunshine (Date)", "Max Wind Gust", "Max Wind Gust Date", 
    "Grass Min Temp", "Grass Min Temp Date"
]

data


How do you want to handle the double date entry for Station 2 / Wind? If you can skip this line it's easy, if not it quickly gets very complicated.

@stef this means the station recorded the same max gust on 2 separate days, so this needs to stay in the table - which certainly complicates things. I'd like to see the simple version if you can help with that? I can maybe figure out a workaround for the second entry

the output appears to be fixed width, so total rainfall for instance will be line[22:29].strip() etc.

Oh I see but will this not lose the subheadings? Ideally I want a dataframe organised by station that has extreme temperature max, extreme temperature max date, extreme temperature min, extreme temperature min date etc.

this idea was to skip the first 8 lines when reading and supply the header manually as you did in write_to_csv

@stef I've added an edit above to do what you asked (I think) but the output is still very messy and full of bad lines etc. however the data does seem correct. Could this be cleaner?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Don't put an answer in the question, that's what the answers section is for :) That said, what's the question? So your code's not working - OK, what do you need help with? Please read [ask]. If you don't really have a question, you might look at How to debug small programs by Eric Lippert and use a Python debugger and/or a regex debugger

As your data seem appear to be fixed width and you tagged your question with pandas, you could use read_fwf:
import pandas as pd

infile = 'table_example.txt'
outfile = 'weather_summary.csv'

colspecs = [
    (2, 21), (22, 29), (30, 36), (37, 42), (43, 49), (50, 55), (56, 63),
    (64, 69), (70, 75), (76, 81), (82, 87), (88, 96), (97, 103),
    (104, 109), (110, 115), (116, 123), (124, 129), (130, 138)
    ]

names = [
    "Station", "Rainfall Total", "Most in Day (Amount)", "Most in Day (Date)",
    "Max Air Temp", "Min Air Temp", "Mean Air Temp", "Max Temp", "Max Temp Date",
    "Min Temp", "Min Temp Date", "Sunshine Total", "Most in Day Sunshine (Amount)",
    "Most in Day Sunshine (Date)", "Max Wind Gust", "Max Wind Gust Date", 
    "Grass Min Temp", "Grass Min Temp Date"
    ]

df = pd.read_fwf(infile, skiprows=8, colspecs=colspecs, names=names)
df = df[~df.Station.fillna('').str.startswith('_')]
df.to_csv(outfile, index=False)

